# deserialized a xml file with different extension

Tags: c#

Can i deserialize a xml file with custom extension? (.hhh and not .xml)? into reveleant object?

Comment: most xml files *don't* have the extension xml; just within the IDE I can think of xsd,resx,xaml,dbml,csproj,config... and outside of programming tools *very few* will be tagged as xml

Answer (score 3):

Of course.

Extensions are totally irrelevant.
All the parser needs is a stream of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The extension is meaningless.

Comment: I would recommend simply making an attempt and trying it for yourself in questions this black and white.  You'd be suprised how much time you can save -- and how much more you'll learn.